# How do I change multiple values in pandas df column to np.nan, based on condition in other column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't have much experience in coding and this is my first question, so please be patient with me. I need to find a way to change multiple values of a pandas df column to np.nan, based on a condition in another column. Therefore I have created copies of the required columns "Vorgabe" and "Temp".

Whenever the value in "Grad" isn't 0 i want to change the values in a definded area in "Vorgabe" and "Temp" to np.nan.

```
print(df)  

    OptOpTemp  OpTemp  BSP  Grad  Vorgabe  Temp
0        22.0    20.0    5   0.0     22.0  20.0
1        22.0    20.5    7   0.0     22.0  20.5
2        22.0    21.0    8   1.0     22.0  21.0
3        22.0    21.0    6   0.0     22.0  21.0
4        22.0    23.5    7   0.0     22.0  20.0
5        23.0    21.5    1   0.0     23.0  21.5
6        24.0    22.5    3   1.0     24.0  22.5
7        24.0    23.0    4   0.0     24.0  23.0
8        24.0    25.5    9   0.0     24.0  25.5
```

So I want to achieve something like this:

```
    OptOpTemp  OpTemp  BSP  Grad  Vorgabe  Temp
0        22.0    20.0    5   0.0     22.0  20.0
1        22.0    20.5    7   0.0     nan   nan      <-one row above
2        22.0    21.0    8   1.0     nan   nan
3        22.0    21.0    6   0.0     nan   nan      <-one row among
4        22.0    23.5    7   0.0     22.0  20.0
5        23.0    21.5    1   0.0     nan   nan
6        24.0    22.5    3   1.0     nan   nan
7        24.0    23.0    4   0.0     nan   nan
8        24.0    25.5    9   0.0     24.0  25.5
```

Does somebody have a solution to my problem?

EDIT: I may have been unclear. The goal is to change every value in "Vorgabe" and "Temp" in an defined area to nan. In my example the area would be one row above, the row with 1.0 in it, and one row among. So not only the row, where 1.0 is located, but also rows above and under.

Comment: Your output does no match your intentions, what is exactly what you want? For example the second row is 0 and the values are nan.

Comment: "Whenever the value in "Grad" isn't 0 i want to change the values in a definded area" What defined area? In your example, you have several rows where you've changed the values to nan even though Grad is 0.

Comment: In my example the area is one row above and one among to the row, where the 1.0 is located. Maybe I  should have added this information, sorry. So not only the row with the one but also some above and some among, based on definition the user of the code can set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain 3 conditions with `|` for `bitwise OR`, for rows above and under `1` use mask with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
mask1 = df['Grad'] == 1
mask2 = df['Grad'].shift() == 1
mask3 = df['Grad'].shift(-1) == 1
```

---

```
mask1 = df['Grad'] != 0
mask2 = df['Grad'].shift() != 0
mask3 = df['Grad'].shift(-1) != 0

mask = mask1 | mask2 | mask3

df.loc[mask, ['Vorgabe', 'Temp']] = np.nan
print (df)
   OptOpTemp  OpTemp  BSP  Grad  Vorgabe  Temp
0       22.0    20.0    5   0.0     22.0  20.0
1       22.0    20.5    7   0.0      NaN   NaN
2       22.0    21.0    8   1.0      NaN   NaN
3       22.0    21.0    6   0.0      NaN   NaN
4       22.0    23.5    7   0.0     22.0  20.0
5       23.0    21.5    1   0.0      NaN   NaN
6       24.0    22.5    3   1.0      NaN   NaN
7       24.0    23.0    4   0.0      NaN   NaN
8       24.0    25.5    9   0.0     24.0  25.5
```

General solution for multiple rows:

```
N = 1
#create range for test value betwen -N to N
r = np.concatenate([np.arange(0, N+1), np.arange(-1, -N-1, -1)])
#create boolean mask by comparing with shift and join together by reduce 
mask = np.logical_or.reduce([df['Grad'].shift(x) == 1 for x in r])

df.loc[mask, ['Vorgabe', 'Temp']] = np.nan
```

EDIT:

You can join both masks together:

```
N = 1
r1 = np.concatenate([np.arange(0, N+1), np.arange(-1, -N-1, -1)])
mask1 = np.logical_or.reduce([df['Grad'].shift(x) == 1 for x in r1])

N = 2
r2 = np.concatenate([np.arange(0, N+1), np.arange(-1, -N-1, -1)])
mask2 = np.logical_or.reduce([df['Grad'].shift(x) == 1.5 for x in r2])
#if not working ==1.5 because precision of floats
#mask2 = np.logical_or.reduce([np.isclose(df['Grad'].shift(x), 1.5) for x in r2])

mask = mask1 | mask2
df.loc[mask, ['Vorgabe', 'Temp']] = np.nan
print (df)
   OptOpTemp  OpTemp  BSP  Grad  Vorgabe  Temp
0       22.0    20.0    5   0.0     22.0  20.0
1       22.0    20.5    7   0.0      NaN   NaN
2       22.0    21.0    8   1.0      NaN   NaN
3       22.0    21.0    6   0.0      NaN   NaN
4       22.0    23.5    7   0.0      NaN   NaN
5       23.0    21.5    1   0.0      NaN   NaN
6       24.0    22.5    3   1.5      NaN   NaN <- changed value to 1.5
7       24.0    23.0    4   0.0      NaN   NaN
8       24.0    25.5    9   0.0      NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Do you also have an Idea on changing not only one above and one among, but 2?

Comment: @JeddyEastside - Give me some time.

Comment: That worked. I don't want to annoy you, but you seem to be a load more skilled than me. If you don't want to spend more time into this, I would totally understand this. The last question I would have: Do you have an idea how to iterate through the colum and define your N = 1 if there is a 1.0 in df['Grad'] and to N = 2 if there is a 1.5 in df['Grad']? In the original data the is not only ones in this column, but numbers from one to two. And i would like to define the N based on the value that is in df['Grad'].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186486/discussion-between-jeddy-eastside-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 5):

Use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.Grad != 0.0, ['Vorgabe', 'Temp']] = np.nan
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   OptOpTemp  OpTemp  BSP  Grad  Vorgabe  Temp
0       22.0    20.0    5   0.0     22.0  20.0
1       22.0    20.5    7   0.0     22.0  20.5
2       22.0    21.0    8   1.0      NaN   NaN
3       22.0    21.0    6   0.0     22.0  21.0
4       22.0    23.5    7   0.0     22.0  20.0
5       23.0    21.5    1   0.0     23.0  21.5
6       24.0    22.5    3   1.0      NaN   NaN
7       24.0    23.0    4   0.0     24.0  23.0
8       24.0    25.5    9   0.0     24.0  25.5
```

Comment: That is what I meant by "area". Not only the row, where the 1.0 is located in "Grad", but also one above and one among. That would be the output I tried to show in my post. Perfect would be, if I could define the "area". So for example change three values above and three values among to nan. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
import numpy as np

df['Vorbage']=np.where(df['Grad']!=0, df['OptOpTemp'], np.nan)
df['Temp']=np.where(df['Grad']!=0, df['OpTemp'], np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.apply(f,axis=1)`, and define `f` to be what you want to do on each row. You description seems to be saying you want

```
 def f(row):
     if row['Grad']!=0:
         row.loc[['Vorgabe','Temp']]=np.nan
     return row
```

However, your example seems to be saying you want something else.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The desired output is, that I can define an area above and among to the row, where the 1.0 is located. And this area should be changed to nan. In my example, the area would be 1 above and 1 among.